# Create PHP array from database with users

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I want to created arrays like this `$user["1"]`, how to I create this from a database?

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) { } 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Account";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $user[$id] = $row["username"];
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Why do you want to convert a numeric key into a string? I don't see any reason to do that.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Because I am making a message system that works with id's. Now I can use `$user["$from_user"]` in the echo

Comment: You can do the same with `$user[$from_user]` or `$user["$from_user"]`. PHP isn't strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it like this, create an empty array `$user` before inserting.

```
$user = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $user[$i] = $row["username"];
    }
}
```